# How to group_by(everything())

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to count unique combinations in a dataframe using `dplyr`

I tried the following:

```
require(dplyr)

set.seed(314)
dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T),
                  b = sample(1:2, 100, replace = T),
                  c = sample(1:2, 100, replace = T))

dat %>% group_by(a,b,c) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

But to make this generic (unrelated to the names of the columns) I tried:

```
dat %>% group_by(everything()) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

Which results in:

```
    a     b     c     n
<int> <int> <int> <int>
1      1     1     1     6
2      1     1     2     8
3      1     2     1    13
4      1     2     2     8
5      2     1     1     7
6      2     1     2    12
7      2     2     1    14
8      2     2     2    10
9      3     1     1     3
10     3     1     2     4
11     3     2     1     7
12     3     2     2     8
```

Which gives the error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : `c(...)` must be a character vector
```

I fiddled around with different things but cannot get it to work. I know I could use `names(dat)` but the columns in the dataframe that need to be in the `group_by()` are depended on previous steps in the `dplyr` chain.

Comment: does your code result in the expected output or in the error?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it solves the task "_I want to count unique combinations_": `count(dat, a, b, c)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function called `group_by_all()` (and in the same sense `group_by_at` and `group_by_if` )which does exactly that.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
 group_by_all() %>% 
 summarise(n = n())
```

which gives the same result,

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 4
> # Groups:   a, b [?]
>        a     b     c     n
>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
>  1     1     1     1     6
>  2     1     1     2     8
>  3     1     2     1    13
>  4     1     2     2     8
>  5     2     1     1     7
>  6     2     1     2    12
>  7     2     2     1    14
>  8     2     2     2    10
>  9     3     1     1     3
> 10     3     1     2     4
> 11     3     2     1     7
> 12     3     2     2     8
> ```

**PS**

```
packageVersion('dplyr')
#[1] ‘0.7.2’
```

Comment: I tried to run it earlier, but somehow got error and didn't check the documentation

Comment: @akrun, very convenient way. I have used it quite a bit (`group_by_at` more)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `.dots`

```
dat %>%
     group_by(.dots = names(.)) %>%
     summarise(n = n())
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   a, b [?]
#      a     b     c     n
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     1     6
#2     1     1     2     8
#3     1     2     1    13
#4     1     2     2     8
#5     2     1     1     7
#6     2     1     2    12
#7     2     2     1    14
#8     2     2     2    10
#9     3     1     1     3
#10    3     1     2     4
#11    3     2     1     7
#12    3     2     2     8
```

Another option would be to use the unquote, `sym` approach

```
dat %>%
    group_by(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
```

Comment: which gives the error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  wrong result size (3), expected 100 or 1`

Comment: I also don't get an error running akrun's code (`dplyr_0.7.2`)

Comment: I was running `dplyr_0.5.0` apparently. In which `dat %>% group_by_(.dots = names(.)) %>% summarise(n = n())` does work (group by underscore). After updating `dplyr` there is no problem anymore with your solution.

Comment: @Wietze314  I also updated with the `syms/UQE` route which might be more relevant in the coming days

Answer (score 4):

In `dplyr` version 1.0.0 and later, you would now use `across()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

Package version:

```r
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.5’
```